# The view 'Index' was not found from pluggin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I tell you that I have an application with netcore mvc that loads plugins from different areas from a main project.

This works perfectly, but when executing the area it throws the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

**InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/TestHome/Index.cshtml /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml**

The area in is called TestArea, but it doesn't raise the views of my pluggins area.

The structure of my plugin is as follows:

[image]

The structure of my main project is as follows:

[image]

In the **Areas/Extensions/TestArea** folder I put the assemblies and in the **Areas/TestArea** folder I put the views.

As I mentioned, load the plugins well and run the controller, but executing it throws me the error that I exposed previously.

The code I use is the following:

**PluginExtensions.cs**

```
public static class PluginExtensions
{

    public static IMvcBuilder AddExtensions(this IMvcBuilder mvc)
    {
        List<string> extensionAssemblies = new List<string>();
        var serviceProvider = mvc.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var hostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Startup>();
        List<string> extensionDirectories = EnumerateExtensionDirectories(serviceProvider).ToList();
        List<string> searchPatternList = new List<string>
        {
            "*Extension.Mvc.dll"
        };
        mvc.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
        {
            foreach(var extensionDirectory in extensionDirectories)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < searchPatternList.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<string> tempList = EnumerateExtensionAssemblies(extensionDirectory, searchPatternList[i]).ToList();
                    if (tempList != null && tempList.Count > 0)
                        extensionAssemblies.AddRange(tempList);
                }//for(int i=0;i< searchPatternList.Count; i++)
                foreach (var extensionPath in extensionAssemblies)
                {
                    var pluginAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(extensionPath);
                    var partFactory = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(pluginAssembly);

                    foreach (var part in partFactory.GetApplicationParts(pluginAssembly))
                    {
                        apm.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
                    }

                    var relatedAssemblies = RelatedAssemblyAttribute.GetRelatedAssemblies(pluginAssembly, throwOnError: true);
                    foreach (var assembly in relatedAssemblies)
                    {
                        if (assembly.FullName.ToLower().IndexOf("extension.mvc.views") >= 0)
                        {
                            **var compiledRazorAssemblyApplicationParts = new CompiledRazorAssemblyApplicationPartFactory().GetApplicationParts(AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assembly.Location));**
                            foreach (var craapf in compiledRazorAssemblyApplicationParts)
                                apm.ApplicationParts.Add(craapf);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            partFactory = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(assembly);
                            foreach (var part in partFactory.GetApplicationParts(assembly))
                            {
                                apm.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
        });
        return mvc;
    }}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".Matios.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".Matios.Antiforgery";
        });
        var iMvc= services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new SessionExpireAttribute());

            options.EnableEndpointRouting = true;
        })**.AddExtensions()**;
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
```

Finally the url that I execute is the following: http://localhost:5000/TestArea/TestHome/Index

Can you help me?

Comment: Couple of things.... You have TestArea/TestHome/Index.cshtml defined twice once in your "plug in" and once in your Website.... I am not sure this would work... Second as far as I undestand the search locations are relative to the current working directory.  So when you put stuff inside "Extensions" how is it going to find what it needs?  I would start by eliminating the TestArea from the Website and placing those "References" in the root of the project not in any folder.

Comment: Also why are you loading the "plug ins" dynamically? I mean you have added them to the main website anyways.... So whats the point?  You might as well just add a reference and save yourself the headaches

Comment: The point is to load the assemblies dynamically, otherwise I would have done it with direct reference and not dynamically.

Comment: Yes but you added them to the main project.... so it defeats the purpose of dynamically loading them...

Comment: Question can you show an image of all the files in your Test.ModuleExtension.Mvc project?

Comment: I figured it out... Look at my answer. I was able to load an area dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by doing the following:

**First The Plug In:**
I created a fully functioning MVC Website with the area I want. 
In this case just a vanilla website decorated the HomeController with:

```
    [Area("TestArea")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
```

Then moved the "stuff" under the TestArea like this:

[image]

**Second Convert To DLL:**
Converted the "Plug In" to a Class Library like this:

[image]

**Third The Host:**
I created a VANILLA website with NO AREAS
Added the "Plug In assemblies" like you did
BUT I added them to the ROOT of the project..... 
Like this:

[image]

**Fourth Area Support:**
To BOTH projects I added the routing support for areas to the Startup class like this:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {//this was added to both projects
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areaDefault",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

**Fifth Changed the PluginExtensions:**
Changed the PluginExtensions class you have to look in the Current directory like this:

```
var extensionDirectories = new List<string> { Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() };
```

**Finally**
I dit NOT add "Views" to the Host Project... Because those should be compiled inside the dll's for the Plugin.... 
As a matter of fact I did not even add areas folder... as each "Area Plugin" should control it's own "Area".

**Here is the result:**
Notice how the URL is to an area that does NOT exist in the current website... It was loaded dynamically!
Hooray!
[image]